# Splitting string of integers into array - elements don't get recognized

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am attempting to split a string of integers into an array in JavaScript.

Originally I had:

```
m.rows[7] = new Array   (8,11);
```

And I am changing it to:

```
var nearby = nearby.split(",");
m.rows[7] = new Array   (nearby);
```

(And setting a variable with the appropriate integers separated by a comma in my level editor. When I print "nearby[0]" to the console I get '8'. When I print "nearby[1]" to the console I get 11)

However, I then have this code in which I attempt to match one of the elements in the array with an element in another array:

```
    for (var i = m.rows[id].length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // If the loop finds an element ID that matches the ID of the last element in the path array, do this:
        console.log('test nearby 2: ' + m.rows[id][i]);
        if (m.rows[id][i] == this.path_array[this.path_array.length-1].id) {
            // Loop through the one array 
            for (var j = all_nodes.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
                // If the ID of one of one of these entities matches the id of the instance that was just clicked
                if (all_nodes[j].id == id) {

                    // Activate that node:
                    all_nodes[j].active = true;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
```

When I actually put "8,11" into the array above manually the above works perfectly. However when I attempt to use "nearby" which I split into the array, it does not. And printing it to the console in "test nearby 2" above, when I use "nearby" "8,11" gets printed. When I manually enter "8,11" into that array I get "11".

I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I'm probably missing something extremely obvious here - can anyone shed some light?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what `nearby` actually is; is it a string with comma-separated values? If so, note that splitting it will result in strings, not actual `Number`s. That *may* be okay, because JS will do type conversion, but it depends on the order of operations. Easier/safer to just make them numbers after the split.

Comment: Dave, Nearby was a string with comma-separated values as you suggest. Minitech's answer below ended up helping me do what I was attempting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how arrays work. In `new Array(8, 11)`, `8` and `11` are *parameters*. In `new Array(nearby)`, `nearby` is *one* parameter. To achieve the functionality you need, however, it's quite simple; `nearby` is already an array, so just assign it:

```
m.rows[7] = nearby;
```

Or, if the type bothers you:

```
m.rows[7] = [parseInt(nearby[0], 10), parseInt(nearby[1], 10)];
```

Note that here I used the array literal syntax, `[]`. `[a, b]` is basically equivalent to `new Array(a, b)`, and you should use the literal syntax when possible for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`nearby` is already an array.  There is no reason to call `new Array(anArray)`.  And in fact, you shouldn't as this will not be what you think it is.

EDIT:

Here is a fiddle that illustrates the problem.  Notice that the first element in the array is in fact an array containing both element, instead of just the first element.

http://jsfiddle.net/V7QLN/